# How do I do bi-directional communications using "Codename One New-Java-Javascript-Interop-API" in my specific use-case?

Tags: codenameone

I have an App that makes intensive use of "browserComponent" and bidirectional communication between Java native code and Javascript embedded inside web-page content.

Now we must make the same thing using the New Async-Java-Javascript-Interop-API recently posted by Codename One.

In this context, We need to bind all buttons present on each page to routines coded in native code (java/kotlin) as soon the page is loaded.
How can we capture "Html Body on-load-event" and how to activate all binds that we need?

And, on the opposite direction, the java code that was triggered by html-buttons mentioned before, interacts with the users. As a result of these interactions, normally it is necessary to modify some values of javascript variables (frequently a javascript-array) and that way allowing update dynamically the document model in the Browser.

Any help on this subject will be very appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming you read this https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-async-java-javascript-interop-api.html and it was missing some information? If so can you be specific about what isn't clear from that?

Comment: Thank you Shai and Steve for the excellent post. It answered several of my doubts. Only one question remains in my mind after reading.
I could see a rich bundle of examples and use cases, but all of them assume the page is already loaded (I think). 
Is it possible put here few lines of code showing
How to register a callback handler in java that must be executed always a new Html is inserted via "setPage" method of component (Body onLoad Event)?
Obs: This handler will bind all buttons to its respective action (Java/Kotlin) in the App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind an `onLoad` event in the same way you always could using:

```
browserComponent.addWebEventListener(BrowserComponent.onLoad, e -> {
    // here you can start writing JS binding code
});
```

For reference this article covers everything else about the binding https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-async-java-javascript-interop-api.html